# Error occurred in react-dom.production.min.js:209 after deploying react app by using aws amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-redux, react-router

I had made one complex react app and tried to deploy it by using aws amplify.

Build was success and I and see the first login page. And I can login with calling backends from the amazon ec2 backend server.

But after login success it shows one error in react-dom.production.min.js file. and can't see anything.
This is the screenshot of my deployed app.

[screenshots of the deployed app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWJFa.jpg)

It works very well when I run it in development mode.
And following is the screenshot of my app in development.

[screenshots of the running app in development](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4ZE5.jpg)

I had used react-md for using NavigationDrawer.

It seems there is an issue that using the combination NavigationDrawer and react-dom-router.

Is there any one who had an experience of similar issue before?

What can I do for solving current issue? Should I use the other things for deploying react app such as netlify?

Thank you.